# Justify button's widths inside 100% width container

Tags: html, css

Trying to do something like this
[Bootstrap: Button-Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified)

my markup is something like this

```
<div class='button-group'>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>
```

if the parent container (.button-group) has css: **width:100%;**
then how to justify buttons so that it will take 33.33% of width per button automatically, or 25% if there are 4 buttons and so on...
how to accomplish this using css?

Tried: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s1h893f/)

Comment: have you tried any thing? like the solution you alluded to in your question(33%) ? might just work.

Comment: its not always sure that it'll contain only 3 buttons. i wanna do it depending on html markup

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `table`. It's not so tricky, take a look:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="button-group">
<tr>
<td><button class="bt">1</button></td>
<td><button class="bt">2</button></td>
<td><button class="bt">3</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table.button-group {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.button-group td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bt {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Wanna see a example on JSFiddle? [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/97jx5p6k/)



### UPDATE



If you don't want to use a table, you can replace the `table` tag with a `div` which has `display: table;` and the `td` tags with `div`s which has `display: table-cell;`
In this case, `tr` is not necessary.

#### JSFiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/97jx5p6k/1/)

Sorry if my english is bad...

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

To keep the HTML as is, your best option is to use `display: flex` (though of course it won't work in older browsers): http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/GLIhc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.button-group {display: flex;}
button {flex: 1 100%;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="button-group">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are willing to add some more markup, you can do it like so: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/wznGK

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.button-group {display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;}
.button-group div {display: table-cell;}
button {width: 100%;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="button-group">
    <div>
        <button>1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>3</button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice maybe i'll keep that as plan B... but is it possible with the specific markup which I provided

Comment: The problem is that the buttons are a little hard to work with. Doing it with `<a>`s instead would be easy.

Comment: OK, I've updated with a demo of doing just with the HTML you provided, using `display: flex`. (Note that it won't work in older browsers, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap a series of `.btn`s in `.btn-group.btn-group-justified`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/t61abqgz/3/)**

html

```
2 buttons
<br>
<div class="group justified">
    <div class="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn default">1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn default">2</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br>3 buttons
<br>
<div class="group justified">
    <div class="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn default">1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn default">2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn default">3</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
```

css

```
.justified {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.group {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.justified>.btn, .justified>.group {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    width: 1%;
}

.justified>.group .btn {
    width: 100%;
}

.group>.btn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.default {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```